# Timing of updates

Tags: upgrade, updates, do-release-upgrade

I am running Ubuntu 19.04 and I would like to update to the new released 19.10 version.

I ran `sudo do-release-upgrade` and I got this message:

```
 Checking for a new Ubuntu release
 No new release found.
```

I thought that it was weird since the 19.10 has already been released
http://releases.ubuntu.com/19.10/

In order to understand what was going on I went to the website http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release, since the instruction `sudo do-release-upgrade` check this page behind the scene, and I have noticed that the entry 19.10 is missing.

Do you know when this page will be updated?

Thank you,
Marco

Comment: Is your system updated? upgrade is only possible when it is. Also how about `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`  or `sudo do-release-upgrade -p`?

Comment: Upgrading to a new upgrade takes a few weeks to a month before it is released for system upgrade.  First few weeks is usually left for testers to find bugs.

Comment: I see, so I will be able to upgrade in a month or so. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you should wait for some time and then check if you are still not getting any updates. Since 19.04 is not a LTS version there are some bugs here and there.

Comment: Naah. I had it running 3 weeks ago and not a single issue :-) If 19.04 works 19.10 won't be a problem.